# How do I find out the driver for my Wireless Mouse connected via USB

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, mouse-wheel

I have a problem with my mouse. It is not working well in the **scroll wheel**. Behaving very clumsy. I *scroll up* and it does it  a bit but then it goes *otherwise* same the other way but in general it goes in favor of *scrolling down*.

Maybe the **Synaptics driver** is doing this since it is a laptop. I can change it settings via **Synclient**.

I would like to disable the Synaptics driver and see how the mouse works in that situation. Since being both active both **USB** and **Synaptics** drivers could be *interacting*.

This is the output of `xinput list`

```
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
```

Comment: Mouse does not use synaptics.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This was the solution to my problem ^ (setting the touch-pad off), it was *interacting* after all. XD